# Have jetty instance (configured through maven) connect to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jetty

Just a quick question but I have been struggling for a while with this now - any help would be appreciated.  I have just managed to get my first jetty instance running by setting it up using maven. Now it runs successfully using mvn jetty:run.

However, I need to have the jetty instance connect to a mysql database.  How can I do this?  all online documentation I have read refers to a start.ini file but I am doing everything through maven so am not sure how this applies.  Has anyone got a simple list of instructions of what I would need to do to have my app connect to mysql?  Preferably using a connection pool.

Thanks for any help you can offer

Comment: You can use http://hibernate.org/orm/ with MySQL, it also backed session management and you can connect throughJDBC to your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use a connection pool so I just recommend you write the code to connect it to MySQL.
first, you will need to import mysql-connector from maven
Add at this few lines to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.35</version>
</dependency>
```

Then if you have created a class that manages the connection to your database. And you don't care much about pooling your connections then

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://{IP_TO_YOUR_SERVER}:{PORT[DEFAULT=3306]}/{DB_NAME}?user={USERNAME}&password={PASSWORD});
```

However, if you want to use a connection pool you probably will need to check "[Jetty/Howto/Configure JNDI Datasource](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource#MySQL)"

And I think this link to stack overflow can help as well.
[JNDI lookup failing with Jetty for JDBC connection pooling with MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216792/jndi-lookup-failing-with-jetty-for-jdbc-connection-pooling-with-mysql)

I have been struggling all morning with the same issue and to be honest I tried the first approach. And this moment I am using that solution.